# Does the CiviCRM API comply with the OpenAPI Specification?

Tags: api

Does the CiviCRM API comply with the [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md)?

Answer (score 1):

No the CiviCRM api does not comply with the open api specification. Is there any reason why you are asking this?

Comment: I am asking because I am responding to an RFP and complying with the OpenAPI spec is a requirement.